# How liquid is 70-80 KU viscosity?

Tags: concrete, paint

How liquid is paint that's rated 70–80 KU in viscosity?

Will concrete absorb paint that's this viscous?

Answer (score 2):

Paint that's rated 70-80 Krebs units in viscosity would give a reading of about 575-875 centipoise on a cup viscometer. That's about as viscous as SAE 50 motor oil at room temperature.

> Will concrete absorb paint that's this viscous?

What does it say on the label? If the label says that the paint is suitable for use on concrete, then you can use it on concrete. Viscosity and absorption are not the most important factors in paint application. For example, steel does not absorb paint at all. Some paints are good for steel, some are not. The same with concrete.

The bottom line is you have to check the label.